# How to implement protected file download with requests and authentication in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, amazon-s3, static

I have a django app where I can upload files. I show my files in an API. Like so:

```
class FileCollection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    store_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_file, null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class FileDownloadAPIListView(ListAPIView):
    """Lists all files.

    """
    queryset = FileCollection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileCollectionSerializer
```

Later I will implement different queries to get specific files.

I'd like to download these files from a script using python without the need to open up a browser or anything like that. I want to make an authenticated API call with requests that gets my file and then saves it to the local computer.

The problem is that my files need to be private and only authenticated users should be able to download it. For my other APIs I am using JWT token authentication.

My question now is: How do I implement this? Do I

a) Save my files in S3 and make an API call to that URL somehow authenticating me with my AWS credentials?
b) Save my files somewhere in my PostgrSQL database and get everything from there with an authenticated API call using JWT. 
c) third option I didn't consider

Also if I use a, b or c how could I go in implementing those?

Option a) I thought could be something like:

```
def get_file(method='get'):

    headers = {
        "Authorization": "JWT " + token
    }

    url = 'http://localhost:8000/linktomyawsstorage'
    myfile = requests.get(url)
    open('/somefolder', 'wb').write(myfile.content)

    r = requests.request(method, ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
```

But I don't know if that still works if my files are in a private storage on AWS. Also I don't know if that is the way one should implement it.

Any suggestions, ideas, help or hints are very much appreciated!

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use S3 presigned URLs.  Have your users authenticate to your application via the UI.  Once authenticated, you can generate for them S3 presigned URLs that they can use to download the file either via their browser or using the command line via curl/wget.

Take a look at the [AWS Python SDK documentation on S3 presigned URLs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html).

You can also just use the Python SDK to make requests to S3 to get the objects of interest.

Comment: thanks Ashaman. That does sound promising. It doesn't seem like the optimal solution, since I need to create URLS all the time. Isn't there a way to perform an authenticated request to a S3 bucket with django requests? That would make it more straightforward.....

Comment: Maybe its also good to know: I only need users to create objects that are in posession of my AWS credentials. So it would be enough if I could make an API call with my AWS credentials that downloads the file.....

Comment: Hmm ok, why don't you do that then?  I'm not sure what I'm missing but why can't you use the AWS python SDK with an access keypair to download the files from S3 after you have authenticated the user's request?

Comment: Because I didn't know if that was the best way to go and if what I wanted to do is actually doable how I imagined it.... And also because I don't really know how to do it with the AWS python SDK :)

Comment: Ah ok, it's pretty straight-forward:  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html.  That to me seems like the simplest solution based on my understanding of your requirements.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will read this and try it. But also, I would have to do 2 requests: One to get my url from the database and then another one to the AWS bucket.... So I though maybe there is a solution for my problem where I can only do a single request.... But I don't really see it.....

Comment: Looks like this person has done something similar although w/ HTTP Basic Auth.  It's apparently open source so you may want to explore how he accomplished it to give you some ideas:  https://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/21/s3-http-basic-auth.html

Comment: thanks my friend! This seems a bit overcomplicated for my use case. I will try this now with AWS python SDK and come back here

Comment: I have a small follow up question on pre signed urls: I have tried to set a private and a static storage folder in my S3 bucket. But all my assets are now private so my css files cant be read. Is it neccessary to have presigned urls or should it work with 2 different storages like described here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html?

Comment: The 2 different buckets seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thank you Ashaman! But django only lets me configure one constant for my static files right?

Comment: I somehow got it to work also in one bucket :) Now I'll try to AWS and python SDK. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I ended up using the pre signed URLs as you said. Works fine with boto3. In my script I can do: ``url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,'Key': object_name}, ExpiresIn=expiration)```. With that I can download it. What I don't really understand though: Where does boto3 take my credentials from? Will that also work on a machine that doesn't have my app running?

Comment: ah I got it :), numerous ways as the doc explains